# Recommended flag for "Performance of X option" questions

Tags: discussion, flags

What is the recommended flag for "Performance of X option" questions? Clearly they are Off-Topic, because the answer depends on a number of factors and specific circumstances. But should it be: Opinion-Based? Too Broad? Are there any specific guidelines?

Comment: "The answer depends on a number of factors and specific circumstances" would lead me to lean towards Too Broad. I believe that at least one mod though has stated that simply getting questions that need improvement on hold is more important than getting the exact close reason right. YMMV.

Answer (score 4):

Those type of questions are almost always too broad.

Most questions in this category fail to specify:

- what kind of performance they are looking for (I/O, CPU, MEM)
- what their dataset look like
- what exact steps/code/tools used to perform the test (tnx @Gimby)
- what OS/Build/platform/Toolset/Hardware they are running on/aiming for
- which optimizations they already tried
- which results they achieved so far
- which goal they want to reach
- how maintainable their code needs to be
- ... other things I missed ...

Some even forget to present any code at all (although that is not limited to only performance question)

Without all this information we can only guess how to reach unknown goals. You can see that those answers will not help the OP, nor any future visitors of the same question.

If you find such question that is lacking any of the above mentioned bullets a voting or flagging to close as too broad is warranted, as is a down vote for being utterly unclear.

When you stumble onto a question where you have doubts about the applicability a close reason feel free to drop in the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) chatroom to ask for advice.

Comment: Things missed: the exact steps/code used to perform the test, because more often than not people do it as wrong as is possible, and invent new ways to do it wrong :) You seem to be making it your mission to answer questions from a year and a half ago! It must have been the summer of silence.

Comment: @Gimby reasonable questions deserve a reasonable answer. Thanks for your suggestion, added.